# Omnibus build failing on debian squeeze

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, omnibus

I am building rpm/deb packages for a software using omnibus(https://github.com/chef/omnibus). The build is failing with the following error:

```
[NetFetcher: openssl] I | Downloading from `https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1p.tar.gz' 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect': SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

I tried upgrading the `openssl` but still the issue persists. Can someone help me identifying the issue and helping me in solving it.